# Simple guest list. Do not show first added record

Tags: php, html, list

I wrote a simple list of guests. The problem is that when you add the first entry in this list is not displayed and each following is added as expected.
Maybe there is a better way to perform this task?
The script is designed to create a simple list of guests. I wonder whether the transmission of using a GET method in this case is appropriate.

```
<body>
<div style="float:left; vertical-align:top;">
    <h2> Guest list </h2>
    <?php

    if (isset($_GET['my_list'])) 
    {
        $list = $_GET['my_list'];
        $explode = explode(',', $list); 
        array_pop($explode); 
        foreach($explode as $name)
        {
            echo $name.'<br>';
        }
    }

    ?>  
</div>
<div style="float:right; vertical-align:top;">
    <h2> New entry:  </h2>
    <form method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="new"><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="my_list" value="
    <?php
        if (isset($_GET['my_list'])) 
        {
            if (isset($_GET['new'])) 
            {
                echo $_GET['new'].','.$_GET['my_list'];
            } 
            else 
            {
                echo ''; 
            }
        } 

        else
        {
            if (isset($_GET['new'])) 
            {
                echo $_GET['new'];
            } 
            else 
            {
                echo '';
            }
        }


        ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Save"><br>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why do you do `array_pop($explode);`?